# Create transactional publication error in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

In attempting to create a new Publication for Transactional Replication in SQL Server, I end up getting the following error, with pretty much no way around it:

> SQL Server could not create publication 'dfdsf'
> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.
> Changed database context to 'farm'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 50000)

For specifics, I did a very basic publication on a single table, with no row filtering. The security accounts used were created [based on this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337475.aspx).

This message does not seem very revealing and I cannot find a way around it. Is there any basic trail I can follow to find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What account are you using to create publication ? Seems to me problem with the account that is being used.

Comment: You nailed it - the account i was using didn't have permissions for the database I was creating the publication in. Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?